# Is there any mathematical theory that can prove that the wrong option of this series problem is not true

Tags: sequences-and-series

If the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n} $ converges, which of the following statements is correct:

$$\begin{array}{c}
&(A)&  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|a_{n}\right|  \; \text{  is convergent}\\
&(B)&  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n} a_{n} \; \text{  is convergent}\\
&(C)&  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n} a_{n+1} \; \text{  is convergent}\\
&(D)&  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_{n}+a_{n+1}}{2} \; \text{  is convergent}
\end{array}$$

I already know the answer is `D`, and know that there is a counterexample $\frac{(-1)^n}{\ln n} $ that can exclude the `A`, `B`, `C` options. But I would like to know whether there are strict mathematical theories that can prove that the conclusions of options `A`, `B` and `C` are incorrect.

Comment: A counterexample is a perfectly valid and rigorous way to invalidate those options; I'm not entirely sure what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some counter examples

$(A) \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ converges by alternating series tests, but $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left|\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\right|=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}$ diverges by the integral comparison test.

$(B) \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ converges, but $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{(-1)^n}{n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}$ diverges

$(C) \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}$ converges by the alternating series test. As$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{-1/n}{((-1)^n/\sqrt{n})((-1)^{n+1}/\sqrt{n+1})}=1$$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{-1}{n}$ diverges by the integral comparison test, it follows that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\left(\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{\sqrt{n+1}}\right)$$ diverges by the limit comparison test.